# Framebuffer creation works in Java but not in NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

The following Java code creates an FBO without errors:

```
int[] texFBO = new int[1];
GLES20.glGenTextures(1, texFBO, 0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texFBO[0]);
GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, 
                    GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
                       GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
                       GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, 
                       GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, 
                       GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
int[] FBO = new int[1];
GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1, FBO, 0);
GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO[0]);
GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, 
                              GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texFBO[0], 0);
Log.d(LOGTAG, "initFBO error status: " + GLES20.glGetError());
int FBOstatus = GLES20.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
if (FBOstatus != GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
   Log.e(LOGTAG, "initFBO failed, status: " + FBOstatus);
```

however the following functionally similar NDK code results in a GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT error:

```
stringstream errs;
glGenTextures(1, &FBO_texture_name);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, FBO_texture_name);  
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, 
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid *) nullptr);   
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);   
if ( (! isGLOk(errs)) || (! glIsTexture(FBO_texture_name)) )
   LOGE("Framebuffer texture create failed (%s)", errs.str().c_str());            

glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);      
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);   
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
                       FBO_texture_name, 0);   
if (! isGLOk(errs))
   LOGE("Framebuffer texture bind failed texture name %d, Framebuffer %d: %s", 
        FBO_texture_name, framebuffer, errs.str().c_str());


//GLint check = -1;   
//glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, 
  GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_OBJECT_NAME, &check);
//if (check != FBO_texture_name)
//    LOGE("Texture name mismatch (%d != %d)", FBO_texture_name, check);

GLenum err = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
if (err != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
{   
   if (err == 0)
   {
       errs << "Error in glCheckFramebufferStatus (is function called from Java method that has the OpenGL context ?): "
            << endl;
     isGLOk(errs);       
   }  
  else
     errs << err << ' ';
  switch (err)
  {
     case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT: errs << "GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT"; break;
     case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT: errs << "GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT"; break;
     //case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DRAW_BUFFER: errs << "GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DRAW_BUFFER"; break;
     //case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_READ_BUFFER: errs << "GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_READ_BUFFER"; break;
     case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED: errs << "GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED"; break;
#ifdef OPENGLES3         
     case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MULTISAMPLE: errs << "GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MULTISAMPLE"; break;
#endif         
     //case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_LAYER_TARGETS: errs << "GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_LAYER_TARGETS"; break;
     case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_LAYER_TARGETS_EXT: errs << "GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_LAYER_TARGETS_EXT"; break;
  }
  LOGE("Framebuffer creation failed texture name %d, Framebuffer %d: %s", FBO_texture_name, framebuffer, errs.str().c_str());
  is_framebuffer = false;
}
else
{   
   is_framebuffer = true;
   LOGI("FBO creation succeeded: %d", framebuffer);
}
```

The above NDK code was called from the same Java method (onSurfaceChanged) as the Java code. I have tried both OpenGL ES2 (Android 4.4) and ES3 (Android 5.0 and 5,1) device and also tried adding a depth (render buffer) but to no avail. Any suggestions on what oafish practice or witless blunder I may have fallen into would be welcome.

Comment: Did you double check that `width` and `height` are passed to the native code correctly? Try logging the values.

Comment: Yes I did check. I also tried hard coding width and height to 256 just in case it was an issue with power of 2 textures, although that should not be the case with ES2 or 3. I also tried allocating the texture memory instead of passing nullptr to glTexImage2D.